# AsyncTask doesn't run simultaneously with second AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i have an AsyncTask

```
private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String WEBURL;
    LoadData(String url){
        this.WEBURL=url;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("Downloading");
        URL url = new URL(WEBURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        String contents="";
        while((count = in.read(buffer))!=-1){
        total+=count;
        contents += new String(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        System.out.println("Downloaded");
        in.close;
    }
}
```

If i try to make two `LoadData`'s by calling

```
new LoadData("http://www.google.com").execute();
new LoadData("http://www.stackoverflow.com").execute();
```

I would expect output:

> Downloading Downloading Downloaded Downloaded

But instead i get

> Downloading Downloaded Downloading Downloaded

Which means that the `AsyncTask`s are not executing simultaneously. Why is this? I thought the point of threading was that this wouldn't happen? + is there a way i can make them run simultaneously without changing too much code?

Comment: You misunderstanding threading. The point of threading is to allow the process as a whole to make forward progress, even if one task cannot. Whether threads execute simultaneously or not will depend on a number of factors including availability of system resources, whether I/O can be performed immediately, and so on. (Though your specific issue is an Android quirk.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) under **Order of Execution**:

> Starting with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

I.e., `new LoadData("http://www.google.com").executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`

Comment: THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR cant be resolved to a variable...im targeting SDK 14

Comment: @clairharrison: `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` is a public data member of `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `executeOnExecutor` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Since API 11, `AsyncTask`s don't run parallel by default. You need to call `executeOnExecutor` with given param to make sure the AsyncTasks run parallel.

You can construct something like

```
if (Build.Version.SDK_INT >= 11){
    myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(...);
}else{
    myAsyncTask.execute(...);
}
```